# Maven Assembly Plugins corrupts exe dll

Tags: dll, exe, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm trying to create a zip file containing, among other stuff of my Java project, a .NET x64 EXE + its manifest + a .NET DLL dependency. It looks like maven assembly plugin corrupts the EXE and the DLL. In fact if I try to execute the file once extracted I get "This app can't run on this PC" (invalid x64 windows application), but if I copy the original files they work normally.

I've tried to google for a solution without success. Am I missing something in maven files?

Plugin declaration in `pom.xml` is:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/windows.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <finalName>${bundle.name}</finalName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

while `windows.xml` content is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<assembly
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
  <id>windows</id>

  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>

  <files>
    <file>
      <source>${launcher.dir}/GetMachineId.exe</source>
      <outputDirectory>bin/utils</outputDirectory>
      <destName>GetMachineId.exe</destName>
    </file>
    <file>
      <source>${launcher.dir}/GetMachineId.exe.config</source>
      <outputDirectory>bin/utils</outputDirectory>
      <destName>GetMachineId.exe.config</destName>
    </file>
    <file>
      <source>${launcher.dir}/MessagingToolkit.QRCode.dll</source>
      <outputDirectory>bin/utils</outputDirectory>
      <destName>MessagingToolkit.QRCode.dll</destName>
    </file>
  </files>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Can you share the entire exception?

Comment: From Event Viewer, Windows Logs > Application: `The program or feature "\??\<dir>\GetMachineId.exe cannot start or run due to incompatibility with 64-bit versions of Windows. Please contact the software vendor to ask if a 64-bit Windows compatible version is available.` (source: Wow64 Emulation Layer). If I replace GetMachineId.exe with the original file and retry, I get Microsoft .NET Framework error dialog reporting `...BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'MessagingToolkit.QRCode...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue.

I was actually using also `maven-resources-plugin` on `${launcher.dir}` with filtering.

Excluding binary files from filtering solved the problem.

**UPDATE:**
In my pom.xml the `maven-resources-plugin` was configured like in the following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>filtering-launcher-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${launcher.dir}</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/launcher</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

With `src/main/launcher` erroneously containing both text file (that actually required filtering) and binary ones (`GetMachineId.exe`, `GetMachineId.exe.config`, `MessagingToolkit.QRCore.dll`).

In order to solve the problem I've moved those binaries in a different folder (`utils`) and modified the assembly file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<assembly
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
  <id>windows</id>

  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>

  <files>
    <file>
      <source>utils/GetMachineId.exe</source>
      <outputDirectory>bin/utils</outputDirectory>
      <destName>GetMachineId.exe</destName>
    </file>
    <file>
      <source>utils/GetMachineId.exe.config</source>
      <outputDirectory>bin/utils</outputDirectory>
      <destName>GetMachineId.exe.config</destName>
    </file>
    <file>
      <source>utils/MessagingToolkit.QRCode.dll</source>
      <outputDirectory>bin/utils</outputDirectory>
      <destName>MessagingToolkit.QRCode.dll</destName>
    </file>
    <file>
        <source>${launcher.dir}/config.xml</source>
        <outputDirectory>bin</outputDirectory>
        <destName>config.xml</destName>
    </file>
  </files>
</assembly>
```

This way `maven-resources-plugin` does not process with filtering the binaries, so they do not get corrupted. It looks like the filtering process treats always the files like they are text ones, so it modifies binaries in such a way that prevents their execution.

Another, more recent, strategy could be this one: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/binaries-filtering.html

Comment: Same problem here. I would have appreciated a short sentence on how to exclude binary files from filtering. But a search machine will tell me soon.

Comment: I had the exact same issue: maven was reading a dll in text mode, and the file ended being corrupted after being copied by the maven-resources-plugin to the target folder. Moving the dll to a separate folder and setting filtering to false did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I've found an easier solution modifying the *pom.xml* just using the *excludes* and *includes* tags at *resources* -> *resource*.

Example:

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.dll</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.dll</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have moved my exe file to separate folder and then used below tag in assembly xml:

```
<files>
  <file>
    <source>some.exe</source>
    <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
    <filtered>false</filtered>
  </file>
</files>
```

Reference taken from: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/filtering-some-distribution-files.html